# Как проверить значение со всеми буквами, которые идут после w+?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть `url = '&search=90sd%we12`

```
var re = /\&search\=\w+/g;
```

Не работает, так как `url.replace(re, '&search=45')` -  выдает `&search=45%we12`, то есть не проходит `%`.
Кто знает как поправить регулярку?

Comment: var re = /\&search\=\w+(\%\w+)*/g;